# Cartoon about an alien that came to Earth, and is helped back to his home planet by a boy

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was a cartoon show, where an alien comes to Earth. A boy helps him, he turns him into a boy with the help of his watch.

After that the boy, the alien and his friends help the alien back to their home with the help of his watch. The watch opens a portal to another world; it also helps the alien to turn him into a boy.

There is an organization, they catch aliens with the help of robots and two agents.

Comment: Could you possibly provide some more details? Such as when you may have watched it, and what channel? Whether it was in English, etc. If you haven't already, I recommend you take a look at [this guide]( https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any additional details.

Comment: If the Earth boy is already a boy, I think you mean the alien turns _himself_ into a boy with the help of the alien's watch. "He turns him into a boy" means he turns someone else into a boy.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably *Linus et Boom* (2009), a French-Korean 3D-animated cartoon, known in English as *My Giant Friend*.

From [TvTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/MyGiantFriend):

> When a big red alien named Boom crashes on his balcony, the 12-year-old Linus has to hide him from the Space Development Center (SDC). Thanks to the Dr. K, Linus acquires the Scire Swatch which allows him, among other things, to put Boom under a human disguise at will. His friends Iris, Monroe and Taki soon join him in his mission to find aliens lost on Earth, free or protect them from the SDC, and safely send them back home.

Indeed, the big red alien gets injected "an electronic chip, specially prepared to be controlled by your [Linus'] watch", as you can see in the episode below (2'17):

The organization (the SDC) is indeed catching aliens, and two agents are appointed to hunt Boom down: Chase and Sandborn, which you can see below, as well as some robots. You can also briefly see these robots [in the cartoon's intro](https://youtu.be/594Tgp7mMCM?t=1m8s), for instance.

[image: SDC agents and robots]

The Scire Watch can open a portal to the aliens' world, as you can see in the following episode, at 5'5 (in French, didn't find an English dub for that one):

---

Found partly by luck, since someone had posted it as [an answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194390/98028), and as always when another ID turns out to be French, it stuck in my mind... Saw the alien thing here, figure I'd give it a try, sheer luck!

Comment: See also [Animation show about 4 kids and 1 red alien, kids save alien from being captured by an evil organisation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/185589/98028), which isn't accepted but likely deals with the same show.